# Graph API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

Can any one suggest how I could remove the cancel button next to login button in the Facebook graph API for iPhone. Where does the code lie?

Comment: You can add your own cancel button, but it wont look good as the facebook button looks different from the UIButton.  Are you using new fbconnect SDK?,  if NO, then Try out the new SDK which have the inbuilt cancel button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default answer is you can't, its a web page in a WebView by Facebook.

But since Facebook iOS SDK is open sourced. You can actually inject javascript into the WebView to remove the button using this function.

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

But this method is probably against the policy of Facebook so do it at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Even if possible to do so programmatically, facebook [**terms and conditions**](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/&rct=j&q=facebook%20graph%20api%20terms&ei=tUWlTa21DZDNrQf1zLzrCQ&usg=AFQjCNGAsACCofJemtw9WCCuyIhSrCZREw&sig2=o-7x-Fdb_EKtdJZDYlJGVQ) do not allow us to alter the UI from the facebook graph api.

Also, altering the UI may render the common user confused..

So, its advisable not to do so..

Thanks!